# Intertwining two text files line by line

Tags: bash

I have two files. 
One file has name with spaces and the other the spaces have been replace with underbar by the mighty and formidable tr commands.

```
cat /tmp/crap2
Effective awk Programming, 3rd Edition.pdf
Fashion Photography by Edward Steichen in the 1920s and 1930s (15).jpg
Fashion Photography by Edward Steichen in the 1920s and 1930s (19).jpg
Fashion Photography by Edward Steichen in the 1920s and 1930s (30).jpg
Fashion Photography by Edward Steichen in the 1920s and 1930s (4).jpg
sed &amp; awk, 2nd Edition.pdf


cat /tmp/crap
Effective_awk_Programming,_3rd_Edition.pdf
Fashion_Photography_by_Edward_Steichen_in_the_1920s_and_1930s_(15).jpg
Fashion_Photography_by_Edward_Steichen_in_the_1920s_and_1930s_(19).jpg
Fashion_Photography_by_Edward_Steichen_in_the_1920s_and_1930s_(30).jpg
Fashion_Photography_by_Edward_Steichen_in_the_1920s_and_1930s_(4).jpg
sed_&amp;_awk,_2nd_Edition.pdf
```

I want to make output like this for display for to the file makinng display one with underbar and the other with not the underbar:

```
Effective_awk_Programming,_3rd_Edition.pdf
Effective awk Programming, 3rd Edition.pdf
Fashion_Photography_by_Edward_Steichen_in_the_1920s_and_1930s_(15).jpg
Fashion Photography by Edward Steichen in the 1920s and 1930s (15).jpg
Fashion_Photography_by_Edward_Steichen_in_the_1920s_and_1930s_(19).jpg
Fashion Photography by Edward Steichen in the 1920s and 1930s (19).jpg
Fashion_Photography_by_Edward_Steichen_in_the_1920s_and_1930s_(30).jpg
Fashion Photography by Edward Steichen in the 1920s and 1930s (30).jpg
Fashion_Photography_by_Edward_Steichen_in_the_1920s_and_1930s_(4).jpg
Fashion Photography by Edward Steichen in the 1920s and 1930s (4).jpg
sed_&amp;_awk,_2nd_Edition.pdf
sed &amp; awk, 2nd Edition.pdf
```

but when i use bash command with while loop and nested for loop I get big mess for outputs:

```
$ while read line ; do  for i in $(cat /tmp/crap); do  echo $i ; done ; echo $line ; done < /tmp/crap2


Effective_awk_Programming,_3rd_Edition.pdf
Fashion_Photography_by_Edward_Steichen_in_the_1920s_and_1930s_(15).jpg
Fashion_Photography_by_Edward_Steichen_in_the_1920s_and_1930s_(19).jpg
Fashion_Photography_by_Edward_Steichen_in_the_1920s_and_1930s_(30).jpg
Fashion_Photography_by_Edward_Steichen_in_the_1920s_and_1930s_(4).jpg
sed_&amp;_awk,_2nd_Edition.pdf
Fashion Photography by Edward Steichen in the 1920s and 1930s (30).jpg
cat /tmp/crap)
cat /tmp/crap
Effective_awk_Programming,_3rd_Edition.pdf
Fashion_Photography_by_Edward_Steichen_in_the_1920s_and_1930s_(15).jpg   
Fashion_Photography_by_Edward_Steichen_in_the_1920s_and_1930s_(19).jpg
Fashion_Photography_by_Edward_Steichen_in_the_1920s_and_1930s_(30).jpg 
Fashion_Photography_by_Edward_Steichen_in_the_1920s_and_1930s_(4).jpg
sed_&amp;_awk,_2nd_Edition.pdf
Fashion Photography by Edward Steichen in the 1920s and 1930s (4).jpg
cat /tmp/crap)
cat /tmp/crap
Effective_awk_Programming,_3rd_Edition.pdf
Fashion_Photography_by_Edward_Steichen_in_the_1920s_and_1930s_(15).jpg
Fashion_Photography_by_Edward_Steichen_in_the_1920s_and_1930s_(19).jpg
Fashion_Photography_by_Edward_Steichen_in_the_1920s_and_1930s_(30).jpg
Fashion_Photography_by_Edward_Steichen_in_the_1920s_and_1930s_(4).jpg
sed_&amp;_awk,_2nd_Edition.pdf
sed &amp; awk, 2nd Edition.pdf
```

I have tried other scripts with changing IFS and then making different cat file right now what i do is

```
paste /tmp/crap /tmp/crap2
```

two file and use vi to make edits

Comment: I'm not on a suitable machine right now but what happens when you try `cat file1 file2 | sort -m`?

Comment: It's not much what you're asking for but I think you may like `vimdiff /tmp/crap /tmp/crap2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 2 file descriptors:

```
while read -u3 c1 && read -u4 c2; do 
    echo "$c1"
    echo "$c2"
done 3<crap 4<crap2
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe `paste` has the `-d,--delimiter` option. So just do

```
paste -d '\n' /tmp/crap /tmp/crap2
```

assuming the cygwin `paste` is similar to coreutils `paste` or BSD `paste`.